# Building a chat client Android app, how should I approach recieving messages?

Tags: android

I'm making an Android application that connects to my computer, with this I am trying to make it so I can send messages back and forth. As of right now messages can be sent and recieved server-side but for my Android application I don't know how to constantly check for messages and update the UI. I'm using a BufferedReader for input and I want to display the messages on a TextView. Here's what I have so far:

```
package com.example.david.chatclient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

/**
* After connecting to server, how can i recieive messages, append it, and then reloop through it
*/


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String IP;
private int portNumber;
private Socket clientSocket;
private PrintWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;
private Button connectButton;
private Button sendButton;
private EditText userMessage;
private TextView chatHistory;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 10.0.2.2 = Android Emulator IP Address (Reaches development machine, not emulator itself)
    IP = "10.0.2.2";
    portNumber = 25565;

    connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    userMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_message);
    chatHistory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chat_history);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void connectClient(View view) {
    ConnectToServer task = new ConnectToServer();
    task.execute();
} // end connectClient


public void sendMessage(View view) {
    String message = userMessage.getText().toString() + "\n";
    writer.write(message);
    writer.flush();
    chatHistory.append("CLIENT: " + message);
    userMessage.setText("");
}

private class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            clientSocket = new Socket(IP, portNumber);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfuly connected, streams are esablished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} // end ConnectToServer


} // end MainActivity
```

Here's what the UI looks like:

https://gyazo.com/dbf99c78ca7874939a404ef7d23d8ff8

Comment: You should take a look at GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)

Comment: If the phones do not always connect to Internet, I suggest SignalR for your case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aproaches.

1. Checking periodically if new message awaits on server this method is called Fetch - this is very battery and data unfriendly.
2. Keeping open connection all time aka push messaging - that's the modern way to go. Google handles this on android and ios with [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)